# Flutter app - debug works fine / release mode gray screen

Tags: android, flutter

For some reason the photos are not loading when I do the release build of my Flutter app.

See video

(debug mode) - works

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B0Xkl4VQ8UL7jkbplFSGeL9GErxZOG-_/view?usp=sharing

(release mode)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Am1bd8s6E8aXxB1TbsE4oQ1Rw2n9alph/view?usp=sharing

What i see in the logs is

```
I/Gralloc4(11559): mapper 4.x is not supported
W/Gralloc3(11559): mapper 3.x is not supported
```

My code that uses map

```
/* TO FETCH PHOTOS */

Photo photoFromJson(String str) => Photo.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String photoToJson(Photo data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Photo {
  Photo({
    this.data,
  });

  List<Datum> data;

  factory Photo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Photo(
    data: List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Datum {
  Datum({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.imageurl,
    this.website,
    this.listenlive,
  });

  String id;
  String name;
  String imageurl;
  String website;
  String listenlive;

  factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
    id: json["_id"],
    name: json["name"],
    imageurl: json["imageurl"],
    website: json["website"],
    listenlive: json["listenlive"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "_id": id,
    "name": name,
    "imageurl": imageurl,
    "website": website,
    "listenlive": listenlive,
  };
}

/* TO FETCH PHOTOS */
Future<Photo> fetchPhotos(http.Client client) async {
  final response =
  //await client.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos');
  await client.get('https://api.drn1.com.au/station/allstations');
  // Use the compute function to run parsePhotos in a separate isolate.
  return compute(parsePhotos, response.body);
}

// A function that converts a response body into a List<Photo>.
Photo parsePhotos(String responseBody) {
  return photoFromJson(responseBody);
}

class PhotosList extends StatelessWidget {
  final Photo photos;
  final uuid;
  FlutterRadioPlayer _flutterRadioPlayer = new FlutterRadioPlayer();

  PhotosList({Key key, this.photos, this.uuid}) : super(key: key);




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 1,
      //  childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
      //      (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4), //childAspectRatio: 200,
      ),
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: photos.data.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return  RaisedButton(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
            textColor: Colors.white,
            color: Colors.black,
            onPressed: () async {  await _flutterRadioPlayer.setUrl(photos.data[index].listenlive+'?uuid='+uuid, "true");
            },

          child: CachedNetworkImage(
            imageUrl: photos.data[index].imageurl,
            placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
            errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
          ),
        );
        // return Image.network(photos.data[index].imageurl, width: 80.0, height: 80.0,);
      },
    );
  }
}

/*END FETCH PHOTOS*/
```

Note that my app works fine in debug mode but not release mode?

In my Main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.radiomedia.drn1">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="drn1"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Build.Gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.radiomedia.drn1"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Github code:

https://github.com/redimongo/DRN1---Flutter-Android

Comment: Hi, I cannot open the video of release mode. it asks for login

Comment: @rya https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Am1bd8s6E8aXxB1TbsE4oQ1Rw2n9alph/view?usp=sharing

Comment: do you have Proguard enabled on your release build config?

Comment: @rya I have no idea how do I check

Comment: under android folder> app > build.gradle file.
android { buildTypes {  release { minifyEnabled true}}}

is minifyEnabled true?

Comment: @rya it does not even have it - i'll post the code in the file above

Comment: then it is not a Proguard issue. It is not an internet issue, right?

Comment: @rya in debug mode it works - it's the release version that does not. Same wifi connection

Comment: @rya I have publicly listed the full app code - if you could see if you can run my code that would be great (debug version work)  - (release plays up)

https://github.com/redimongo/DRN1---Flutter-Android